# phonegap java runtime-error logging

Tags: java, cordova, logging, runtime-error

Is there a way to log Java runtime errors/exceptions in a PhoneGap/Cordova mobile application. 
I just want to be able to see what is going on during execution. I'd like to store exceptions to a text file and then have the file sent back to me.
Thank you